# create multidimensional array from matching array keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Need to create a multidimensional array by matching the keys in an array.

array 1:

```
[
 'slide_name_1'  => 'lorem ipsum',
 'slide_title_1' => 'lorem ipsum',
 'slide_name_2'  => 'lorem ipsum',
 'slide_title_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
]
```

I need to create this:

```
[0] => array (
       'slide_name_1'  => 'lorem ipsum 1',
       'slide_title_1' => 'lorem ipsum 1',
       )
[1] => array (
       'slide_name_2'  => 'lorem ipsum 2',
       'slide_title_2' => 'lorem ipsum 2',
       )
```

I was thinking of running some nested foreach loops and matching just the number portion of the keys (ex: `substr($key, strrpos($key, '_') + 1);`).

Of course this has proven to be more difficult than i had anticipated. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, what is matching? Last number? And what is wrong with provided code for `strrpos`?

Comment: You could use `explode('_', $key)` and then use the last element of that.

Comment: If order and number of elements always the same, you can split array into chunks with `array_chunk`

Comment: I was thinking of matching just the number portion of the keys, yes. strrpos works fine to pull them. Where i run into a wall is creating a new multidem array.

Comment: @u_mulder order will be the same but it could be any number of name/title sets. The array is the result of a dynamically created form

Comment: @Barmar strrpos works fine. This issue is populating a new array so that all elements ending 1 are in one array, all elements ending in 2 in another, 3 in another, etc....

Comment: @kash101 Create an associative array, and use that number as the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. No need for nested `foreach` loops though. Just use one.

Like:

```
$arr = array (
 'slide_name_1'  => 'lorem ipsum',
 'slide_title_1' => 'lorem ipsum',
 'slide_name_2'  => 'lorem ipsum',
 'slide_title_2' => 'lorem ipsum',
);

$result = array();
foreach( $arr as $key => $val ){
    $k = substr($key, strrpos($key, '_') + 1); //Get the number of the string after _

    //Normally, this line is actually optional. But for strict PHP without this will create error.
    //This line will create/assign an associative array with the key $k
    //For example, the $k is 1, This will check if $result has a key $k ( $result[1] ) 
    //If not set, It will assign an array to $result[1] = array()
    if ( !isset( $result[ $k ] ) ) $result[ $k ] = array(); //Assign an array if $result[$k] does not exist

    //Since you already set or initiate array() on variable $result[1] above, You can now push $result[1]['slide_name_1'] = 'lorem ipsum 2';
    $result[ $k ][ $key ] = $val . " " . $k; //Push the appended value ( $value and the number after _ )
}

//Return all the values of an array
//This will convert associative array to simple array(index starts from 0)
$result = array_values( $result );
```

This will result to:

Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [slide_name_1] => lorem ipsum 1
            [slide_title_1] => lorem ipsum 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [slide_name_2] => lorem ipsum 2
            [slide_title_2] => lorem ipsum 2
        )

)
```

Comment: ...and this will be O(n). It's much better than nested loops(minimum O(n^2))

Comment: Awesome.....I was on my forth nested foreach just to get semi close. This works perfectly. Thanks Much

Comment: Happy to help @kash101

Comment: @Eddie Not to be a pest, I absolutely appreciate the script. But could you explain this line (if ( !isset( $result[ $k ] ) ) $result[ $k ] = array();)? Im trying to wrap my head around why this line works the way it does.

Comment: @kash101 No worries. :) Please check my explanation above. Please let me know if you have questions

Comment: @Eddie Got it. Was trying do do something similar in one of the many nested loops by getting the key from the last element added to the array. was the closest i got. Of course i also ended up with 65 indexes on that attempt. Thanks again for the script and especially the explanation. Much appreciated!